# How to get ewsUrl for Outlook add-in using Outlook for iOS or Android

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an add-in that supports Desktop, OWA and Mobile.

The add-in allows users to upload emails with attachments.

On Desktop, I can get the mailbox item and get the property ewsUrl to retrieve the appropriate endpoint to then make follow-on API calls to get the attachments.

However, the ewsUrl is not supported on iOS or Android per the instructions here:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/1.5/Office.context.mailbox?product=outlook&version=v1.5

So any ideas how I can support this feature? Can I assume that all ewsUrl will be "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx" since the user is using IOS or Android?

Comment: ewsURL is not supported for mobile platforms like you pointed out. you can use resturl to achieve the behavior you want..

Comment: Does the REST API support all Add-in Platforms, like on-premise Exchange 2013?  I thought it only supported online versions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations

Comment: On-premise Exchange 2013 doesn't support REST API.

Comment: You add-in will need to switch between ews and rest URL if you want it to run on all platforms and on-prem config.

Answer (score 1):

Add-ins on Outlook iOS and Outlook Android do not support `ewsUrl` and `makeEwsRequestAsync`. Exchange On-Premise 2013 does not support REST and since Outlook Mobile only supports the REST protocol, Outlook Mobile add-ins require Exchange 2016 or Exchange Online. In order to support both scenarios, you will need to switch between using EWS for Exchange 2013 and REST for Exchange 2016 and Exchange Online depending on the client, or implement a middle tier service that can communicate via EWS with Exchange 2013 on behalf of the add-in for Outlook iOS and Outlook Android.